# Openconnect for Cisco VPN doesn't recognize private key file - asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

Tags: linux, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, vpnc

I'm trying to use my *Synology DS212* NAS box also act as VPN gateway to my companies VPN. Sadly, they only use *Cisco ASA* and to complicate stuff even further, we've got to use personal certificates (which is of course more secure, but more complicate to get going…).

So I compiled OpenConnect v4.06 from http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/. As a very basic test, I tried to build a connection by manually invoking openconnect, passing along the key and cert files, like so:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.3 --library-path /opt/lib \
 /opt/openconnect/sbin/openconnect \
  --certificate=$VPN_CFG/alexander.crt \
  --sslkey=$VPN_CFG/alexander.key \
  --cafile=$VPN_CFG/Company_VPN_CA.crt \
  --user=alexander --verbose <ip>:443
```

It fails :(

```
Attempting to connect to <ip>:443
Using certificate file $VPN_CFG/alexander.crt
Using client certificate '/CN=alexander@tech.doma.in/OU=Company VPN'
5919:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1315:
Loading private key failed (see above errors)
Loading certificate failed. Aborting.
Failed to open HTTPS connection to <ip>
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

When I run the same command with the same cert/key files on a Ubuntu 12.04 box, it works:

```
openconnect \
 --certificate=$VPN_CFG/alexander.crt \
  --sslkey=$VPN_CFG/alexander.key \
  --cafile=$VPN_CFG/Company_VPN_CA.crt \
  --user=alexander --verbose <ip>:443
Attempting to connect to <ip>:443
Using certificate file $VPN_CFG/alexander.crt
Extra cert from cafile: '/CN=Company AG VPN CA/O=Company AG/L=Zurich/ST=ZH/C=CH'
SSL negotiation with <ip>
Server certificate verify failed: self signed certificate

Certificate from VPN server "<ip>" failed verification.
Reason: self signed certificate
Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view: yes
Connected to HTTPS on <ip>
GET https://<ip>/
[…]
```

Well… The error on the NAS is this:

**5919:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1315:**

Any ideas, what's causing this?

On Syno, I use OpenConnect 4.06. On Ubuntu, I just compiled and installed to a custom location OpenConnect 4.06 as well.

Thanks,
Alexander

Comment: I must have done some editing errors, when I manipulated the key file. Using openssl to do the snipping, it worked fine:

openssl pkcs12 -in alexander.skwar.p12 -nodes -clcerts -nokeys > ClientCert.pem;
openssl pkcs12 -in alexander.skwar.p12 -nodes -cacerts -nokeys -out CaCert.pem;
openssl pkcs12 -in alexander.skwar.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out Key.pem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I could solve it by manipulating the private key PEM file a little bit.
It contained the usual header and footer boilerplate

> "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"
>
> "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"

This was perfectly valid for verification with openssl; I could get sane output from the openssl command.

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -noout -text
```

But for openconnect it was not specific enough.

I changed the boilerplate to

> "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
>
> "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

i.e. I added the "RSA" identifier.
(of course without the quotes in the PEM file).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you try connecting to your Cisco AnyConnect network via a normal Linux distribution first, for instance Ubuntu.

> $ sudo openconnect http://$gateway/Full-Access --script
>   /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script --user $USERNAME

Is how I login via openconnect to my AnyConnect installation.

You need to install both openconnect and vpnc for this to work.